# A die and a coin are tossed one after the other

Tags: probability

A man throws a coin and a die alternately. If starts with the coin, what is the probability that he gets a $5$ or $6$ on the die before he gets a head on the coin?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: @chinni Yes can you show us your attempt please?

Comment: @BLAZE And here I was, thinking you are trolling me :)

Comment: wouldn't there be infinite attempts here ?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think there ought to be a sample space, because I could throw a coin and never get a head in 1000 attempts, with a probability of $0.5^{1000}$, or with 10^8 attempts etc.

Comment: @inspd it is potentially infinite attempts, yes, however the *expected time* as well as the probability is going to finite and easily calculable using well known methods.

Answer (score 6):

### Solution using matrices:

This can be described using a markov chain with the following transition diagram:

[image]

Which can then be described using the following transition matrix:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&.5&0\\0&1&0&\frac{1}{3}\\0&0&0&\frac{2}{3}\\0&0&.5&0\end{bmatrix}$

with rows and columns corresponding to the game states $\text{Coin}_{win}, \text{Die}_{win}, \text{Coin}_{turn}, \text{Die}_{turn}$ respectively and since the game starts with throwing the coin, we start with initial state vector $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

This is in the form: $A=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&S\\\hline 0&R\end{array}\right]$

This is an absorbing stochastic matrix, and so we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A^n = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&S(I-R)^{-1}\\\hline 0&0\end{array}\right]$

By calculating the corresponding matrices and multiplying by your initial state vector, you will find the resulting probabilities.

Also of interest is the matrix $(I-R)^{-1}$ which is known as the *fundamental matrix*, where you can also easily gather additional information as to what the expected time is until an end-game state is reached.

---

For additional examples like this, see some of my other similar answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1150730/179297), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1153883/179297), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118352/chance-of-winning-simple-dice-game).  For more information on this method, I recommend PatrickJMT's video series on the subject which begins [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvYTGEZQTEs).  (*Note: in PatrickJMT's videos, he uses rowvectors as opposed to column vectors.  The theory is identical, but everything is transposed to the notation I use here*)

---

### Solution without matrices:

Note that the chance the coin wins on the first turn is $\frac{1}{2}$.  In the case that the coin wins on the second opportunity, that implies that the coin lost on the first flip, the die lost the first roll, and the coin wins on the second flip and so happens with probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$.  In the case that the coin wins on the third flip that implies that the first two coinflips are tails, and the first two die-rolls are low, and the third coinflip is heads.  This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$.

This can easily be generalized.  The chance that the first head is before the first high roll and that the first head occurs on the $(i+1)^{\text{st}}$ coin-flip is $(\frac{1}{2})^i(\frac{2}{3})^i\frac{1}{2}=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i\frac{1}{2}$.

Summing over all cases, we get then that the probability of getting a head before a high roll is: $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^k\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

This is a geometric sum and so will converge and can be calculated using known techniques.

Calculating the probability that a high roll is before a head can be found similarly (or simply by noting that it is the complement of the probability calculated by the sum above).

Note, the theory behind this answer matches exactly with the hidden theory behind the solution using matrices.  Which you learn first largely depends on the person and what career track you are on.

Comment: Excellent image and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start like this:

Let discrete random variable $X=$ The event of getting a $5$ or $6$ on the die

and define  $P(\text{$X$ is a $5$ or $6$})= \frac{1}{3}$

Let discrete random variable $Y=$ The event of getting a Head on the coin

and define $P(\text{$Y$ is a Head})= \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

When in the course of the game one of $1,\ldots,4$ is thrown we are again at the start. The probability $p$ of winning  therefore satisfies
$$p={1\over2}\left({2\over3}\cdot p+{1\over 3}\cdot 1\right)\ ,$$
which leads to $$p={1\over4}\ .$$